# Adding values to an empty 2D list (TypeError)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, typeerror

I'm trying to add values to an empty 2d list with this code:

```
values_to_go = [(7, 6, 2, 2, 350.0, '6', '11/05/2022\n', 7), (8, 6, 2, 1, 350.0, '08:30-10:30\n', '15/06/2022\n', 7), (9, 6, 2, 1, 350.0, '16:00-18:00\n', '25/08/2022\n', 7)]

list = []
for i in range(len(values_to_go)):
    list[i][0] = values_to_go[i][0]
    list[i][1] = values_to_go[i][5]
    list[i][2] = values_to_go[i][6]
    list[i][3] = values_to_go[i][2]


print(list)
```

But I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Expected output:  `values_to_go = [(7, 6, 11/05/2022\n, 2), (8, 08:30-10:30\n, 15/06/2022\n, 2), (9, 16:00-18:00\n, 25/08/2022\n, 2)]`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many mistakes in this code.

The `values_to_go` list is not a 2d list. The `(7)` or any number between parentheses is totally equal to a number without any parentheses. If you want to make it a tuple, you should tell python that these are not parentheses around the number; but these are tuple signs. So `7` is totally equal to `(7)`. You should use `(7,)` to tell python that this is a `tuple` with one member which is `7`. So this `... = values_to_go[i][0]` will be OK.

Another mistake is the part that you've written to append members into the empty `list`. You cannot point to a non-existent member of a list with this expression: `list[i][0]`. There is no `list[i]` and therefore obviously there is no `list[i][0]`. If you want to append into the end of the list, you should just do it:

```py
list.append(anything)
```

This would be something like this:

```py
>>> values_to_go = [(7,), (8,), (9,)]  # or [[7], [8], [9]]
>>> some_list = []
>>> for i in range(len(values_to_go)):
...     some_list.append(values_to_go[i][0])
...
>>> print(some_list)
[7, 8, 9]

>>> # and if you want to make it 2D:
>>> some_list = []
>>> for i in range(len(values_to_go)):
...     some_list.append([values_to_go[i][0]])
...
>>> print(some_list)
[[7], [8], [9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create your list, it is empty, so basically you can't access any position of it, first you have to create them you can do this with the `.append()` function.

Your code could look like this:

```
mylist = [[],[],[]]

for i in range(len(values_to_go)):
    mylist[i].append(values_to_go[i][0])
    mylist[i].append(values_to_go[i][5])
    mylist[i].append(values_to_go[i][6])
    mylist[i].append(values_to_go[i][2])
```

output: `[[7, '6', '11/05/2022\n', 2], [8, '08:30-10:30\n', '15/06/2022\n', 2], [9, '16:00-18:00\n', '25/08/2022\n', 2], ]`

Some extra tip, `list` is a Python reserved word, so don't use it as a variable name

Comment: Thanks - I've put the full example above now, if that makes more sense?

Comment: Essentially, how do I insert into position [0][0] of the empty list?